# A Nonzero Alternating Bilinear Form on the Space $P_1(F)$ Over $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, vector-spaces

Can anybody think of an example of a nonzero alternating bilinear form on the space $P_1(F)$ over $F$.

$F$ is a general field like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

$P_1(F)$ is the set of all polynomials of at most degree $1$ over the field $F$.

Comment: What is $F$ and what is $P_1(F)$?

Comment: @JiangweiXue See my recent edit.

Comment: In that case, $P_1(F)$ is a two dimensional $F$-vector space, and up to scalars, there is only one nonzero alternating bilinear form on a two dimensional space.